# Imputation where some data points should not be imputed

Tags: scikit-learn, data-imputation, mice

I am trying to impute the RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) measurement from different WiFi access points. In this instance, data can be missing for two reasons: either the laptop did not look for the WiFi access point but it could have gotten a reasonable RSSI value (I call this unobserved) or the WiFi access point is completely unavailable and should rightly be a NaN (Not a Number) value (I call this unobservable) - e.g., the AP (Access Point) is in a building in a different city.

Are there imputation methods where imputations are only provided if there is evidence that an imputation is possible (i.e., not for the unobservable values)?

I have tried naively doing this with the Iterative Imputer module in python (I think this is similar to MICE). This does not work - the unobservable values just get something like the mean value of all the data. Another technique I have wondered about is having two models, with the precursor model somehow identifying the probability that the data should or should not be imputed. Another technique I wonder about is encoding the unobservable values, say with a negative value, but I don't see how I could distinguish unobservable data from unobserved data in the raw data effectively.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I have also wondered about doing this with some kind of auto-encoder to impute the answers. This again faces the problem of distinguishing between the unobserved and unobservable data.

Comment: This paper by Rubin called 'Inference and missing data' seems relevant, although I'm still getting through it: http://math.wsu.edu/faculty/xchen/stat115/lectureNotes3/Rubin%20Inference%20and%20Missing%20Data.pdf